# Is it possible to change the volume of the phone from within the application?

Tags: java, android

I am thinking of making an application which at certain time periods (set by the user) disables the volume of the phone and just enables the vibration; for example, if someone calls during that period, the phone simply vibrates instead of ringing. Is there any method that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is very much possible. I will try to explain in detail.

By disable I will assume that you want to **set the volume to lowest**,

Get a reference to the `AudioManager`

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Now, you need to know what is the maximum volume supported by the device

```
int streamMaxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
```

Now you should have the **maximum value** in the integer variable, suppose you get 6.

So the possible values you can set your volume is in the **range 0 to 6**. (0 being silent and 6 being the loudest)

```
//set to lowest
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES|AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

//set to loudest
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 6, AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES|AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND)
```

This gives you **complete flexibility on the volume level** you want to set.

Now if you need yo change the ringer mode to `VIBRATE`, just do this

```
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

if you want to simply set it to `SILENT`, just do this

```
audiManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

and if you want to revert it back to `NORMAL`, just do this

```
audiManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Whoo hooo this is awesome mate. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to know I could help. The best way to say thanks in StackOverflow is by accepting the answer and upvoting. I have also updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AudioManager class to change the volume.  From the android reference:

```
Use Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) to get an instance of this class.
```

To set to vibrate use the setRingerMode method.  The constants are:  RINGER_MODE_NORMAL, RINGER_MODE_SILENT, or RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE.  You can use getRingerMode() to check what is currently in use.